# how to use express-mung middleware with Nestjs app

Tags: typescript, express, logging, nestjs, response

I'm trying to log response body of nestjs app with express-mung

In express app. It would be like

```js
const mung = require('express-mung');

function redact(body, req, res) {
    // do something with body...
}

module.exports = mung.json(redact);

// app.js
app.use(require('./redact'))
```

With nestjs, I tried something like the code below but it didn't work.

```js
import * as mung from 'express-mung';

export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    function redact(body: any, req: any, res: any) {
      console.log('logger');
      console.log(body);
      console.log(req);
      console.log(res);

      return body;
    }
    consumer.apply(mung.json(redact)).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

Thankyou.

Comment: Do you get an error or is it just not firing?

Comment: it just not firing